# Join two tables on the basis of two case obtained from parent table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a coin table which provides all the information about uploaded coins, and there is an owner table which gives information about the owner of a particular coin. In the coin_owners table, there is field 'ownership_mode' which will be either '**transfer**' or '**Reward**'. If the mode is '**transfer**', I want to left join the transfer table, and if the mode is '**Reward**', I want to join the rewards table.

I have tried this using the **CASE** clause, but it's not working.

The query I tried is:

```
SELECT * , coins.id AS CoinId FROM coins
LEFT JOIN coin_owners ON coin_owners.coin_id = coins.id
LEFT JOIN (CASE WHEN coin_owners.`ownership_mode` = 'transfer' THEN transfer_detail ON   transfer_detail.transfer_to = coin_owners.current_owner
AND transfer_detail.transfer_from = SUBSTRING_INDEX( coin_owners.previous_owner,  ',',  '-1' )  
WHEN coin_owners.`ownership_mode` = 'Reward' THEN rewards ON rewards.`coin_ids` = coin_owners.coin_id
AND coin_owners.`ownership_mode` =  'Reward'
AND STATUS =  '0'
) WHERE coins.id ='".validString($_REQUEST["coinId"])."' LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: Maybe you could UNION the `transfer_detail` and `rewards` with the addition of a flag column indicating which table the data came from. More probably however, this problem points to a flaw in your schema design.

Comment: i have tried UNION also but it is still not working...please help me with the query that works if you can....Thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: please provide table details

Comment: "Coins" table have basic coin info fields i.e id,creation_date,coin description ,coin_number. "coin_owners" contain feilds for owner info i.e id, coin_id(foreign key of coins),current_owner(foreign key of user registration) , previous_owner(comma separated foriegn key of user registration ) "Transfer_detail" table contain info of coin transfer from one user to other user feilds are id, transfre_to ,transfer_from, coin_id and "rewards" table contains info if coin is rewarded to user from admin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks a lot...but i have used the following query and it works fine >---->

```
SELECT * , coins.id AS CoinId FROM coins

LEFT JOIN coin_owners ON coin_owners.coin_id = coins.id

LEFT JOIN transfer_detail ON transfer_detail.coin_id = coin_owners.coin_id AND transfer_detail.transfer_to = coin_owners.current_owner AND transfer_detail.transfer_from = SUBSTRING_INDEX( coin_owners.previous_owner,  ',',  '-1' ) AND coin_owners.`ownership_mode` =  'transfer'
LEFT JOIN rewards ON rewards.`coin_ids` = coin_owners.coin_id  AND coin_owners.`ownership_mode` =  'Reward' AND STATUS =  '0'

WHERE coins.id ='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_REQUEST["coinId"]))."' LIMIT 0,1
```

thanks to all of you for the help

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is an expression, you can't use that inside a table reference. You'll have to handle both cases using separate queries which you can then combine using `UNION`:

```sql
(
  SELECT …
  FROM coins
  LEFT JOIN coin_owners ON coin_owners.coin_id = coins.id
  LEFT JOIN transfer_detail
    ON transfer_detail.transfer_to = coin_owners.current_owner
    AND transfer_detail.transfer_from =
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(coin_owners.previous_owner, ',', '-1')
  WHERE coin_owners.ownership_mode = 'transfer'
  AND coins.id = ?
UNION ALL
  SELECT …
  FROM coins
  LEFT JOIN coin_owners ON coin_owners.coin_id = coins.id
  LEFT JOIN rewards
    ON rewards.coin_ids = coin_owners.coin_id
    AND STATUS =  '0'
  WHERE coin_owners.ownership_mode = 'Reward'
  AND coins.id = ?
)
LIMIT 0,1
```

You'll have to make sure that the columns of both queries match, perhaps by insering `NULL` values into those which don't have a corresponding value in one of the queries.

Also note that you should not insert request parameters into the string the way you did unless you made absolutely sure that the passed value is safe against SQL injection. Better to use prepared statements, which is why I substituted `?` in my query instead.